# Determine a generator set for the solution set relative to the linear system: Ax = b, where

Tags: linear-algebra

$$[A \mid b] = \begin{bmatrix}-3 & 6 & -1 & 1 & -7\\
1 & -2 & 2 & 3 & -1\\
2 & -4 & 5 & 8 & -4
\end{bmatrix}$$

To find the solution, I have that find the parametric solution for the linear system and start write the generator set for the parametric vectors?

Comment: Is $b=(-7,-1,-4)^t$?

Answer (score 0):

Rref the system gives
$$\begin{matrix}1&-2&0&0&3\\0&0&1&2&2\end{matrix}$$
Now equalizing yields to
$$\begin{matrix}
1&-2&0&0&3\\
0&-1&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&2&2\\
0&0&0&-1&0
\end{matrix}$$
So the solution is 
$$\begin{pmatrix}3\\0\\2\\0\end{pmatrix}+r\begin{pmatrix}-2\\-1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}+s\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\2\\-1\end{pmatrix}$$
where $r$ and $r$ are arbitrary real numbers.